# $P,Q,R$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $V=P \cup Q \cup R$ , then must one of $P,Q,R$ be equal to $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P,Q,R$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $V=P \cup Q \cup R$ , then is it true that one of $P,Q,R$ must be equal to $V$ ? I know the result about subspaces that tells that if for subspaces $A,B$ , $A \cup B$ is also a subspace then $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$ , but for this three union case I cannot make any headway , Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: [here][1] is a similar question.Look at it.


 


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858576/prove-that-the-union-of-three-subspaces-of-v-is-a-subspace-iff-one-of-the-subs

Comment: @SaunDev See the solution given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/858656/81360)