# A linear operator $T:V\rightarrow V$ has a cyclic vector iff $f_T=m_T$ (minimal polynomial=characteristic polynomial)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, generalized-eigenvector

I want to prove the following statement:

> Let linear operator $T:V\rightarrow V$ ($V$ is $n$-dimentional). Then there exists a vector $v$ such that $\left\{ v, Tv, ..., T^{n-1}v \right\}$ form a basis of $V$, iff $f_T=m_T$.

(Actually, the $\Rightarrow$ direction is quite easy. I need to prove the other direction.)

I've seen couple of answers to this problem in this site, all using the "Rational Canonial Form", which is something I wasn't tought in the course (but I am familiar with the Jordan Form).

Moreover, the only proof I've found on the internet is [this](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/when-are-the-characteristic-and-the-minimal-polynomials-of-a-linear-map-equal/), which seemed to be promising, until I got to this sentence, which unfortunately seems to be a mistake:

> See that $V_i$ is a subspace of $V$, for all $1 \leq i \leq m$, and
>   $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^m V_i$. Therefore $V=V_k$, for some $1 \leq k \leq m$.

I don't know if that's true for infinite vector spaces, but for finite ones, such as $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ it's certainly isn't.

Any step towards a proof would be appriciated (as well as an explanation for the suspicious claim stated above). Thank you!

Comment: The claim is certainly true over infinite vector spaces.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60698/if-a-field-f-is-such-that-leftf-rightn-1-why-is-v-a-vector-space-over) for details on that claim

Comment: Note that the answers at the duplicate question do not mention the Rational Canonical Form (though only one of them addresses the harder direction you ask about explicitly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the degrees of the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ and minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $T:V\to V$ coincide.

One can express $V$ as a direct sum of the generalised eigenspaces of $T$. If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $T$, then
$$
V=V(\lambda_1)\oplus\cdots\oplus V(\lambda_k),
$$ 
where $V(\lambda_j)=\{v\in V: (T-\lambda_j)^\ell v=0\,\,\text{for some $\ell\in\mathbb N$}\}$. Each of these generalised eigenspaces is $T-$invariant. Set $T_j$ the restriction of $T$ to $V(\lambda_k)$, and let $p_j(x)$ and $m_j(x)$ the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $T_j$, respectively. In fact we have that $p(x)=p_1(x)\cdots p_k(x)$ and
$$
m(x)=lcm\{m_1(x),\ldots, m_k(x)\}=m_1(x)\cdots m_k(x),
$$
since the $m_j$'s are pairwise prime. And since, $m(x)$ and $p(x)$ have the same degree, then $m_j(x)=(x-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j}$, where $\mu_j$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda_j$ in $p(x)$.

Hence $(T_j-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j-1}\ne 0$ and $(T_j-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j}= 0$. Thus there exists a $v_j\in V(\lambda_j)$, such that
$$
V(\lambda_j)\ni (T_j-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j-1}v_j\ne 0.
$$
In fact $\{v_j,Tv_j,\ldots,T^{\mu_j-1}v_j\}$ is a basis of $V(\lambda_j)$.

Finally set
$$
v=v_1+\cdots+v_k.
$$
Then $\{v,Tv,\ldots,T^{n-1}v\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Indeed, if 
$$
0=c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=p(T)v,
$$
then $p(T)v_j=0$, for all $j=1,\ldots k$. Hence $(x-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j}$ divides $p(T)$, and hence the characteristic polynomial of $T$ divides $p$. Thus $p\equiv 0$, since $\deg p<n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I would like to ask you about two clarifications:

Comment: 1. You assume that the characteristic polynomial splits, right? But that's fine because we can always extend a field to its algebraic closure and it can't "destroy" our cyclic basis.

Comment: 2. Why is the sum of those cyclic vectors cyclic? Assume we have $v_1, Tv_1$ as a basis for one space and $v_2, Tv_2$ as basis for the second one. Then our list is $v_1+v_2, Tv_1+Tv_2, T^2v_1+T^2v_2, T^3v_1+T^3v_2$. Who said that it works?

Comment: For the second clarification. Note that $T^kv_j\in V(\lambda_j)$, for all $k$. Assume that $$ p(T)v=c_0v+c_1Tv+\cdots+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0.$$ Then $ p(T)v_j=0$ and hence $(x-\lambda_j)^{\mu_j}$ divides $p(T)$.

Comment: @35T41 It would be challenging to prove this statement without the use of eigenvalues and generalised eigenspaces, as this requires algebraically closed fields.

Comment: Why is that so challenging? Just replace the irreducible factors $X-\lambda$ by more general monic irreducible polynomials.