# For a finite extension $K/F$ of degree $>1$, prove that $K$ is not the union of finitely many proper intermediate fields.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $K/F$ be a finite extension of degree $>1$. Prove that $K$ is not the union of finitely many proper intermediate fields.

Since $K/F$ is a  finite extension, we can write $K=F(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ for some $a_i\in K$. First consider the case $|F|=\infty$. Then $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n \in K$ which does not belong to any of the proper intermediate fields since otherwise $K=F(a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_n)\subset M$, where $M$ is an intermediate field. A contradiction. So $K$ is not the union of finitely many proper intermediate fields.

Can anyone show me how to proceed in the case of $|F|<\infty$.

Thanks

Comment: For $|F|=\infty$, this is even true without the field structure: Any vector space over $F$ is not a union of finitely many proper subspaces. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60698/96384 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/26/27465 (which even cover some finite cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$I do not think your argument is quite correct. For instance for $F = \Q$ and $K = \Q(\sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2})$, but $\sqrt[4]{2}+ i \sqrt[4]{2} -\sqrt[4]{2} -i\sqrt[4]{2} = 0$.

Or to take Crostul's example $K = \Bbb F_p(x,y) / \Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p)$, with $F = \Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p)$, we have $K = F(x, y)$, but $K/F$ is not a simple extension, so that $F(x + y) \subsetneq K$.

Rather, in the case when $F$ is infinite, proceed by induction on  $\Size{K:F}$.

If there are no intermediate $L$ such that $F \subsetneq L \subsetneq K$, we are done.  This covers the induction basis when $\Size{K:F}$ is $1$, or a prime number.

Otherwise, let $L$ be a *maximal* (with respect to inclusion) such intermediate extension. By induction, $L$ is not a union of proper subfields. Let $a \in L$ be an element which is not in any proper subfield of $L$.

It follows that *$L$ is the only proper subfield of $K$ in which $a$ is contained*. For, if $a \in N$, with $N \ne L$ a proper subfield, then $N$ does not contain $L$, as $L$ is maximal, so $N \cap L$ is a proper subfield of $L$, and it contains $a$.

Let $b \in K \setminus L$.

Now $K$ is a union of finitely many proper intermediate fields $M_{1}, M_{2}, \dots, M_{n}$, and each of the infinite elements $a + \lambda b$, for $\lambda \in F$, lie in one of them. Then there must be a proper intermediate fields $M = M_{i}$, for some $i$, which contains infinite elements of the form $a + \lambda b$, for $\lambda \in F$, It follows that $a, b \in M$. Thus $a \in M \ne L$, a contradiction.

Comment: But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: @pie, sorry, *very* bad example, I have changed it.

Comment: But why write $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2})$ as $\Q(\sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2})$ since $\{\sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2}\}$ has to be a basis for $K$, in order to write like that, but its not.

Comment: @pie what do you mean by a basis? And in any case the symbol $F(a, b, c, \dots)$ is commonly used to denote the smallest extension of $F$ that contains $a, b, c, \dots$, with no further assumption on $a, b, c, \dots$.

Comment: Ok, but there is a theorem in Patrick Morandi's book that says that if $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $K$ is finitely generated over $F$. That means that $K$ has a finite $F$-basis. Will my proof be valid then?

Comment: @pie , Crostul's example still applies here. His extension is finite (the degree is $p^{2}$), but it is not simple, so you will never be able to realize it as $K = F(a_{1}+ \dots + a_{n})$, as you are trying to do, no matter what the $a_{i}$ are.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$As another example, let $\omega$ be a primitive third root of unity. Then $\omega$, $\omega^{2}$ are a basis for the extension $K = \Q(\omega, \omega^{2})$ of $\Q$, but $\omega + \omega^{2} = -1$, so $\Q(\omega + \omega^{2}) = \Q$ is a proper subfield of $K$.

Answer (score 5):

For finite $F$, you have the following result:

> If $F$ is a finite field, and $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, then there exists $a \in K$ such that $K=F(a)$.

This means that there is no intermediate field containing $a$. Thus, any union of intermediate fields does not contain the element $a$ (hence it does not contain $K$).

Comment: So essentially there is no difference between the case $|F|=\infty$ and $|F|<\infty$?

Comment: My argument works for all *simple* extensions. However, there exist non-simple extensions, such as $\Bbb F_p(x,y) / \Bbb F_p(x^p,y^p)$, for $p$ a prime number. In such extensions, you need a different argument. In particular, the proof you posted in your question does not work.