# Index of multiplicative group in field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k\subset K$ a field extension. Assume that $K$ is infinite. Then the index of $k^∗$ in $K^∗$, $[K^∗:k^∗]$

(as groups) cannot be finite. How can I prove this?

If $k$
is finite then I know how to solve this since, if $\mid k\mid=q$ then , if we assume that $[K^∗:k^∗]= n$ is not finite, we have that $K$ can be partitioned into $n$ disjoint sets with $q$ elements. So $\mid K\mid =nq$

not finite, therefore contradiction.

I dont know how to prove it for k
is infinite as well.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695527/10513), no?

Comment: Sorry, I thought once a question is closed you cannot open.

Comment: Also @Jyrki's comment answered to your question. The definition of $K^*/k^*$ finite is $K^* = \bigcup_{j=1}^J a_j k^*$.