# What does it mean when we say the absolute value of a field $F$ as $|F|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to read the question below
[If a field $F$ is such that $\left|F\right|>n-1$ why is $V$ a vector space over $F$ not equal to the union of $n$ proper subspaces of $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60698/if-a-field-f-is-such-that-leftf-rightn-1-why-is-v-a-vector-space-over)
and got stuck at the notation $|F|$. I know if it's used in real or complex number it just means the magnitude of the number but I'm confused when it's used in the context of a field $F$.

Comment: It refers to the number of elements in $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the usual notation for the cardinality of a set (number of elements).

Comment: So for example if F is a set of integers ranging from 0 to 1000 does it mean |F| = 1001?

Comment: Yes. It is also not a field, but this is not relevant to this specific notation.

Comment: Wait I seem to have some misunderstanding of the concept of field can field F be described as set of F^1, F^2, F^3,… and so on?

Comment: Field is a set with two operations (addition and multiplication) which satisfy the usual addition and multiplication laws. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ are fields. There are also finite fields, the simplest examples are the sets of residues modulo a prime number $p$ (for example in a field with 2 elements we have $0 + 0 = 1 + 1 = 0$, $0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1$, $0\cdot 0 = 0\cdot 1 = 1\cdot 0 = 0$, $1\cdot 1 = 1$). If a field $F$ is finite, then it contains a special element $g$, called primitive element, such that $F = \{0, 1, g, g^2, g^3, \dots, g^{|F| - 2}\}$.

Comment: It's better if you write a new question if you have question about fields.